# How to perform long division on polynomials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$$\frac{x^6 - 3x^5 + x^4 - 2x^3 - 3x^2 + x - 3}{x^2 + 1}$$

I got the answer in the book, but I can't figure out how it comes up with the x for $$\ { -2x^3 + 3x^3 }$$

Comment: What is your question then?

Comment: How to write out long division for mathjax! Also, how the problem I wrote comes up with a three. I was going to write out to the point I got, but I can't figure out long division here!

Comment: Do you mean x^2+1/x^6.....Or x^6...../x^2+1?

Comment: X^6/x^2 + 1 is what i meant

Comment: Do you have an image or document or something?

Comment: Writing out long division is rather messy; see [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867785/way-to-show-long-division-symbol-in-mathjax).

Comment: How do I add a image to my question?

Comment: Do you mean $-2x^3 + 3x^3$?

Comment: Yes I do, N.F. Taussig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
\begin{align*}
x^6 - 3x^5 + x^4 - 2x^3 + x - 3 & = x^4(x^2 + 1) - 3x^5 - 2x^3 + x - 3\\
                                & = x^4(x^2 + 1) - 3x^3(x^2 + 1) + x^3 + x - 3\\ 
                                & = x^4(x^2 + 1) - 3x^3(x^2 + 1) + x(x^2 + 1) - 3\\
                                & = (x^4 - 3x^3 + x)(x^2 + 1) - 3
\end{align*}
so the quotient is $x^4 - 3x^3 + x$ and the remainder is $-3$.

Comment: Ok I understand it a lot better now, but I thought for the answer it was fot the x $$\ {x^2}$$ not $${+ 1}$$

Comment: When you divide, you first determine what you must multiply $x^2$ by to obtain $x^6$, which is $x^4$.  Then we multiply $x^4$ by  $x^2 + 1$ to obtain $x^6 + x^4$.  That leaves a remainder of $-3x^5 - 2x^3 + x - 3$.  We then determine what we must multiply $x^2$ by to obtain $-3x^5$, which is $-3x^3$.  We multiply $-3x^3$ by $x^2 + 1$ to obtain $-3x^5 - 3x^3$, which leaves a remainder of $x^3 + x - 3$.  Next, we determine what we must multiply $x^2$ by to obtain $x^3$, which is $x$.  We multiply $x$ by $x^2 + 1$ to obtain $x^3 + x$, which leaves a remainder of $-3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin {align}\frac{x^6 - 3x^5 + x^4 - 2x^3 + x - 3}{x^2 + 1}&=x^4+\frac{- 3x^5 - 2x^3 + x - 3}{x^2 + 1}\\&=x^4-3x^3+\frac{x^3+x-3}{x^2+1}\\&=x^4-3x^3+x-\frac 3{x^2+1} \end {align}$$